# How to Properly Pass Input Field Data from Bootstrap to .NET CORE MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, razor

I'm using Bootstrap 5 and .NET Core 6/MVC for the first time. I would like to pass user input data from the input group below to my Employees controller.

Right now, I can pass parameters doing this:

```
<div class="input-group p-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Details", "Employees", new { id = 1})'">Search by Name</button>
</div>
```

However, I would like to pass what the user enters into the input box instead, something like:

```
type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Details", "Employees", new { id = userInputData})'"
```

Can anyone please provide an example?

Thank you.

Comment: How about using form to pass the data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a demo you can refer to it:

In the view:

```
<form asp-action="Details" asp-controller="Employees">
    <div class="input-group p-3">
        <input type="text"  name="Name"class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit">Search by Name</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

EmployeesController:

```
public class EmployeesController : Controller
 {
     public IActionResult Details(string Name)
     {
         return View();
     }
 }
```

result:

[image]

Comment: I will give this a try. I ended up being able to accomplish this by pointing my original onclick call to a JavaScript function. Always good to know more than one way though.